# Is there an alternative to Adobe PhoneGap and Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I just want a framework that allows me to build cross platform apps with HTML5 for at least iOS and Android. The problem that I'm having here is that I can't build PhoneGap or Appcelerator Titanium apps for iOS since I don't have a $99 developer subscription. I might have one in the future, but for now I can't. Is there anything like these frameworks around that doesn't require a iOS serial? **I don't want to use one of those online tools that don't require coding.** Preferably something like PhoneGap so I can access some of the phone's sensors, like the GPS and Camera.

Comment: How do you plan to publish to iOS without a serial? Unless you don't care about the AppStore, that is...

Comment: Well isn't there a free or at leas cheap service so I can publish on the app store without owning a serial?

Comment: you can develop everything and test it in the simulator. If you want your app on a real device you need the payed account to get certificates to sign your app. (or you need to jailbreak the device)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to publish in the App Store, you need a developer account. In order to get into the App Store, your app must first go through Apple's internal approval process, and you can only apply for that approval if you have an account.

The only way to publish in the App Store *without* your own account is to piggyback on *someone else's* account (e.g., publish it under a friend's account). It's unlikely that any publication service would let you piggyback on their account: what if you tried to publish malicious code and got their account in trouble with Apple?

If you don't need to publish in the App Store, your unapproved iOS app is still runable on jailbroken devices. If you do want to have your app in the App Store, you must get an account.

Comment: Then would there be a way to publish an app legally without jail breaking? Say like publishing on a website? Would that be legal?

Comment: No, sadly. I'm little hazy on the details, but here's how it basically works: once an app clears approval, Apple digitally signs it. A non-jailbroken iOS device will refuse to run an app that has not been blessed with Apple's signature (which is a large reason why people jailbreak in the first place). You need an account to get approved, which you need to get the signature, which you need to get iOS to agree to run the app.